# Why Euclidean Geometry is not a modern deductive system?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

i'm a physicist and i'm enjoying studying geometry.
What i dont understand is why the euclidean geometry system doesn't respect the modern formulation of a deductive system. 
Can you explain this completely ?

Comment: Since Euclid, geometry has been axiomatized. So what ?

Comment: A modern axiomatic treatment of Euclidean geometry was deveoped by [Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) in 1899.

Comment: "Elementary" Euclidean geometry was formulated in first-order logic with identity by [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) in 1959.

Comment: Before we explain anything, you ought to explain why you think modern formulations (there are many, you can’t have missed them) are not “deductive systems”, whatever you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Euclid fails to account for all assumptions he makes. Take, for instance, the first theorem of the elements, that you can erect an equilateral triangle on any segment. In the proof he assumes that two circles which look like they ought to intersect actually intersect in a point. This is not started anywhere, neither as an axiom nor as a theorem.

Comment: I doubt that Euclid knew about the "modern deductive systems".